# Почему разные notification на разных девайсах?

Tags: java, android, android-notification

Мне нужно имплементировать кнопки под уведомлением

У меня 2 девайса `Samsung S5` и `Meizu MX5`

Пуш который я получаю на `Meizu MX5` выглядит так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пуш который я получаю на `Samsung S5` выглядит так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот мой код

```
public void With_buttons(View view) {
    Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
            R.drawable.ic_android_black_24dp);

    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, ResultActivity.class);
    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
    stackBuilder.addParentStack(ResultActivity.class);
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(this)
            .setVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_android_black_24dp)
            .setContentTitle("Wonderful music")
            .setContentText("My Awesome Band")
            .setLargeIcon(icon)
            .addAction(R.drawable.ic_android_black_24dp, "Previous", resultPendingIntent) // #0
            .addAction(R.drawable.ic_android_black_24dp, "Pause", resultPendingIntent)  // #1
            .addAction(R.drawable.ic_android_black_24dp, "Next", resultPendingIntent)     // #2

            .build();

    mNotificationManager.notify((int) System.currentTimeMillis(), notification);
}
```

Почему получается эта разница? Я ожидаю увидеть кнопки на самсунге, но их нет...

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Кнопки эти не со всех версий ОС работают. Второй вариант, видимо, слишком старевший.

Comment: `Samsung S5` не такой уж и старый, скорее Самсунг чего-то там лишнего вырезал из системы при портировании :)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Наоборот самсунг бежит на 5.1 а мейзу на 5.0

Answer (score 2):

Воспользуйтесь [NotificationCompat](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.html) и помните что `ActionButtons` работают только начиная с Андроид 4.1

**Дополнение**
Попробуте на S5 стандартную оболочку вместо поделки от Самсунга
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.launcher

**Дополнение 2**
Еще рекомендуют для Самсунгов использовать ненулевое значение параметра `requestCode` для `PendingIntent`

```
PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(1, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Comment: Я работаю с версией не ниже 5.0...  NotificationCompat  не помог... Очень странно получается конечно(

Comment: Значит надо писать письма благодарности в Самсунг :)

Comment: См. дополнение к ответу

Comment: Да но я ж не буду просить каждого юзера своего приложения менять интерфейс)) Я думал, может есть какое нибудь стандартное решение...

Comment: Можете нарисовать свой лейаут с кнопками и добавить его setContent (RemoteViews views)

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko, это только чтобы удостовериться где проблема.